# Implementar banderas estilo C# en C++

Tags: c#, c++

Estoy adaptando el algoritmo generador de laberintos escrito en **C#** a C++.

Me he encontrado con un tema nuevo para mi: **Banderas**
Conozco como implementar enumeradores en c++, prácticamente es igual, pero no entiendo como implementar las banderas.

En concreto este es la bandera:

```
[Flags]
public enum CellState
{
    Top = 1,
    Right = 2,
    Bottom = 4,
    Left = 8,
    Visited = 128,
    Initial = Top | Right | Bottom | Left,
}
```

He hecho el enumerador:

```
public enum CellState {
    Top = 1,
    Right = 2,
    Bottom = 4,
    Left = 8,
    Visited = 128,
    };
```

Como debo implementar las banderas en c++?

Answer (score 2):

Podrias hacer algo como esto:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

enum CellState{
    Top = 1,
    Right = 2,
    Bottom = 4,
    Left = 8,
    Visited = 128,
    Initial = Top | Right | Bottom | Left
};

int main(void){

    CellState estado = Top;

    if(estado & Initial){
        cout << "Celda Initial" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "Celda NOT Initial" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Resultado**

> Celda Initial

Al realizar la implementación de las banderas en un mismo enumerador:

`Top | Right | Bottom | Left`

Podemos hacer la extracción de un valor distinto a ellas usando el operador:

`&` -> Solo un ampersand

Para ello aplicamos la instrucción:

`if(estado & Initial)`

Devuelve `true` siempre y cuando el valor sea distinto a los del flag (bandera).

Comment: Eso quiere decir que al momento de declarar la bandera poner `Initial` es correcto? Los valores de `Initial` son los que vamos a revisar.

Comment: Exacto, tu puedes poner el valor que quieras

Comment: De todas maneras la comparacion se hacer con el operador de bytes `&`

Comment: Exactamente igual que en __C#__, correcto?

Comment: Y si, las banderas en C/C++ se hace `FLAG1 | FLAG2 | FLAG3`

Comment: De hecho, hay muchos comandos que toman como parametro las banderas asi separadas e.g. `chmod()`

Comment: Realmente hace mucho que no toco C++, estoy desactualizado, pero voy a comprobar, cuando lo compruebe te pongo el chulito, muchas gracias.

Comment: Vale, tu me diras si te funciona, igual en caso tal la pregunta se puede pasar al chat, para conversar si tienes dudas

Answer (score 1):

Una forma bastante cómoda de mantener estos enumerados es crearlos a partir de desplazamientos binarios:

```
enum CellState
{
  Top.    = 1 << 0,
  Right   = 1 << 1,
  Bottom  = 1 << 2,
  Left    = 1 << 3,
  Visited = 1 << 7,
  TopLeft = Top | Left,
};
```

Como estoy escribiendo desde el móvil, lo cual es tedioso, y su uso es exactamente el mismo que el comentado en la respuesta de @IvanBotero por el momento no añado ejemplos de uso.si son necesarios los añado cuando esté frente al ordenador.